# Using call back function between two project

Tags: c#, callback, delegates

I have a console application which continuously receives messages and saves those messages to a database. And I have another project which has a method that takes a message and checks if this message contains certain information. Now I want use a delegate to create a pointer for the check method and pass this pointer to the console application. Both projects are in the same solution. How can I do that?

Comment: Can please post some code here to make you query more clear?

Answer (score 1):

You probably can't, because it sounds like from your description that the two programs are running in separate processes.  Perhaps you could watch for new messages to your database, or set up a pipe between the two.  In order to use a delegate your programs would need to be in the same process space.

If I have mis-read your post and one project is an exe and the other a dependent dll, then you can do what you are thinking.  You can search for "C# event delegate examples".  If you have a problem post some example code.